# Swift Compiler SegFault when initializing Object from Type

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, crash, fault

I am currently working on an iOS app using Swift. I have a custom DataSource that needs to know the Type of the model that it has to provide. I have a custom Protocol, that has one method.

```
protocol JSONModel {
    init(json: JSON)
}
```

Then, there are several models that implement the protocol. All of them have different properties, but are the same otherwise.

```
class CurrentDownload: JSONModel {

    let someProperty: String

    required init(json: JSON) {
        someProperty = json["someProperty"].stringValue
    }

}
```

My DataSource has a property that is of type JSONModel.Type

```
private let modelClass: JSONModel.Type
```

When i try to initialize a new instance of my modelClass i get a segmentation fault. Initialization of the model is done by

```
let model = modelClass(json: modelJSON)
```

Unfortunately, the compiler crashes on that line.

```
Swift Compiler Error
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
1.  While emitting IR SIL function 

@_TFC14pyLoad_for_iOS21RemoteTableDataSourceP33_56149C9EC30967B4CD75284CC9032FEA14handleResponsefS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ for 'handleResponse' at RemoteTableDataSource.swift:59:13
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to fix this or on how to work around this issue?

Comment: Try restarting xcode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried restarting Xcode, but unfortunately it did not fix my problem.

Comment: If you copied that piece of code from net, try rewriting it by hand. There could be BOM characters. Also optional values can cause this.

Comment: I did write that code on my own. I just copied it from Xcode to Stackoverflow and removed unnecessary bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this problem isn't too hard.

Usually with Swift segmentation faults are when you try to set the value of a constant (let) quantity, or try to set the value of something that hasn't been properly declared.

I can spot one such instance here:

```
required init(json: JSON) {
   bytesLeft = json["someProperty"].stringValue
}
```

There's two things wrong with this example. You have a (designated) initialiser which terminates without setting the property *someProperty* and you haven't declared the variable *bytesLeft*.

---

So now the problem (which I *really* should have spotted before) is that * modelClass* just is not a class (or otherwise initialisable type). To cannot directly access a protocol, you can only access a class conforming to a protocol. The compiler didn't spot this because you did something sneaky with *.Type*.

When I say access, I mean functions and properties, including initialisers.
Only a class can create an instance of a class, which has itself as the type of the instance, and protocols can't have bonafide instances themselves.
If you think carefully about it, it is impossible to well-define what you are trying to do here. Suppose we had the protocol

```
 protocol JSONModel {
     init(json: JSON)
 }
```

but then *two classes*:

```
class CurrentDownload: JSONModel {
    let someProperty: String
    required init(json: JSON) {
        //Some other code perhaps.
        someProperty = json["someProperty"].stringValue
    }
}

class FutureDownload: JSONModel {
    let differentProperty: String
    required init(json: JSON) {
        //Different code.
        differentProperty = json["differentProperty"].stringValue
    }
}
```

whereas before one might argue that

```
JSONModel.Type(json: JSON)
```

(this code is equivalent to your code) should compile and run because we have given an implementation of *init*, we now can't deny that there is confusion - which implementation should we use here?? It can't choose one, and most would argue that it shouldn't try, and so it doesn't.

What you need to do is initialise with some class.
If you are looking for a minimal class that adheres to *JSONModel* and no more, you'll need to write such a class e.g.

```
class BasicJSONModel: JSONModel {
    let someProperty: String
    required init(json: JSON) {
        //Some other code perhaps.
        someProperty = json["someProperty"].stringValue
    }
}
```

Then do

```
private let modelClass: BasicJSONModel//.Type not needed with a class

let model = modelClass(json: modelJSON)
```

of course this is probably silly and one may just write

```
let model = BasicJSONModel(json: modelJSON)
```

**Or** you could just write a common superclass if the protocol's only use is for this:

```
class SuperJSONModel {
    let someProperty: String//This is not needed of course and you could just strip down to the init only.
    init(json: JSON) {
        //Some other code perhaps.
        someProperty = json["someProperty"].stringValue
    }
}
```

and then is you wanted to check that some object is "conforming" to the what was the *JSONModel*, you simply check that it is a subclass of *SuperJSONModel*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, the error you spottet only happend when copying the source to stackoverflow. That error is not there in my code. I improved my original question to fix that.
Sorry about that!

Comment: Had another look. There you go. ^ :)

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer. I now use a common superclass and everything works as expected. However, there are some annoyances with this approach. 1) All subclasses do have to call super.init(json: json) in their initializers. 2) There is a superclass with an empty initializer and someone could initialize that very superclass. The superclass should be abstract and never be initialized directly.

Comment: As your solution comes comes very close to what i searched for and I don't have a nicer solution, i will accept your answer!

Comment: Thanks for the tick :)
So regarding (1), yes, that can't really be avoided. Why don't you just have a protocol as you did originally and then just don't have any kind of abstract superclass? Regarding (2), if you don't want an abstract superclass with common properties then why did you ever want to initialise a common protocol/class with the *modelClass(json: modelJSON)*?

Comment: Well, I implemented a data source for my UITableViews. As the data source will be used in various tables, it needs to support different UITableViewCells and different classes for its items. My plan was to have a protocol, that defines common methods that all model classes should implement. Then, when initializing the data source, i pass in the type of a model object, so the data source knows which model it has to use.

Comment: Right, but why did you need
private let modelClass: JSONModel.Type
and the ability to initialise the protocol itself?

Comment: Well, I don't know. What else could I have done? The Protocol is the only thing my models had in common. What I was trying to do is: have a variable that is AnyClass that implements a certain protocol. Using AnyClass however is not possible, as the compiler complains: 'Cannot specialize non-generic type AnyClass'. That's why I tried using the protocol.

Comment: Right, so you can have the type of the variable as the type of the protocol, but when you actually give the variable a value, it must be a class conforming to the protocol (tell me if you're struggling with that step). If I understand what you were trying to say originally, then at some point you do want to specialise (surely this is when the owning class is initialised) and you know which specific model you want, so make it then. If you ever wanted to initialise the protocol then you didn't know what to specialise the model as, and you probably didn't need to specialise in that way.